# Jest ESBuild mocking modules

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, esbuild

With Angular v16 we got Jest in developers preview. Under the hood it's not only Jest but also ESBuild for building the app.

The old methods work no longer.

```
jest.mock('module-name', ...)
```

doesn't do anything as the module name changes when the app gets built for testing. Or, sometimes it even gets embedded into the file!

We also cannot use

```
import * as module from '...';

jest.spyOn(module, 'method')
```

because it throws an error that the "method" is not writable (or smth similar).

How should we mock JS modules now?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't mock a named export directly in an EsModule.

When you use the new builder `@angular-devkit/build-angular:jest`, it's esbuild underneath so you'll get standard es modules. (Not commonjs).

Look at the following example :

```
// foo.ts
export const foo = () => {
  return 'foo';
};

// test.spec.ts
import * as foo from './foo';

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'foo'));
```

Will output :

```
{
  get: [Function: foo],
  set: undefined,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: false
}
```

As you can see, that the function is not configurable so jest will not be able to mock it.

On the other hand methods are OK :

```
// foo.ts
export class Foo {
  static staticFoo() {
    return 'staticFoo';
  }
  foo() {
    return 'foo';
  }
}
```

With the following test:

```
  it('myTest', () => {
    const fooInstance = new foo.Foo();

    jest.spyOn(foo.Foo, 'staticFoo').mockReturnValue('staticBar');
    jest.spyOn(fooInstance, 'foo').mockReturnValue('bar');

    expect(foo.Foo.staticFoo()).toBe('staticBar');
    expect(fooInstance.foo()).toBe('bar');
  });
```

The mocking will be fine.

Comment: But we should be able to mock modules somehow. To make our unit tests non-integration.

Comment: I guess it should be possible to make ESBuild output the exports as configurable?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround the `jest.mock` not working issue.

Disclaimer: this have been tested in a node environment with `jest-esbuild` as the transformer so the setup might vary with angular.

Given this very simple module

```
// myModule.ts
export const bar = '1';
```

used in this file

```
// foo.ts
import { bar } from 'myModule';
export const foo = () => bar; // bar = 1
```

if you setup your test such as `jest.mock()` is declared **before** your imports (since babel is not hoisting these before the imports) **and** you use `require()` to import your file, you'll be able to mock the module as wanted.

```
// __tests__/foo.test.ts
jest.mock('../myModule', () => ({ bar = 3 }));

const { bar } = require('../myModule'); // bar = 3
const { foo } = require('../foo'); // foo() = 3
```